# override function delete js

Tags: javascript, object

i try to override function delete in inheritance object, but it didn't work. what i do not correct

```js
function Card(name, balans) {
  this.name = name;
  this.balans = balans;
}
Card.prototype.delete = function(money) {
  return this.balans = this.balans - money;
}

function DeditCard(name, balans) {
  this.name = name;
  this.balans = balans;
  delete = function(money) {
    if ((balans - money) > 0) {
      return balans = balans - money;
    } else {
      console.log('error');
      return balans;
    }
  }
}
DeditCard.prototype = Object.create(Card.prototype);
let card0 = new DeditCard("First person", 10);
console.log(card0.balans); //10
card0.delete(80); //must be error
console.log(card0.balans); // must be 10
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` function for `DeditCard` should be `DeditCard.prototype.delete`, not a local function in the constructor.

And it needs to use `this.balans`, not `balans`, just like `Card.prototype.delete`.

```js
function Card(name, balans) {
  this.name = name;
  this.balans = balans;
}
Card.prototype.delete = function(money) {
  return this.balans = this.balans - money;
}

function DeditCard(name, balans) {
  this.name = name;
  this.balans = balans;
}
DeditCard.prototype = Object.create(Card.prototype);
DeditCard.prototype.delete = function(money) {
  if ((this.balans - money) > 0) {
    return this.balans = this.balans - money;
  } else {
    console.log('error');
    return this.balans;
  }
}
let card0 = new DeditCard("First person", 10);
console.log(card0.balans); //10
card0.delete(80); //must be error
console.log(card0.balans); // must be 10
```